# get of Backbone Model is sowing undefined data

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have created a backbone model as follows

```
var note_model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    default    : {
        HistoryKey  : "",
        InsertDate  : "",
        MemberKey   : "",
        NoteDate    : "",
        ContactNote : "",
        UserId      : ""
    },
    initialize : function(note) { 
        this.HistoryKey  = note.historykey;
        this.InsertDate  = note.insertdateUTC;
        this.MemberKey   = note.memberkey;
        this.NoteDate    = note.notedateUTC;
        this.ContactNote = note.contactnote;
        this.UserId      = note.userid; 
        console.log(this.get('HistoryKey'));
    }
});
```

Now i have created a collection where a url is defined and i populated the model by using the fetch method of collection.Now after populating the model whenever i'm accessing the model data using

```
model_object.HistoryKey
```

I'm getting the data but when i'm trying to use

```
model_object.get("HistoryKey")
```

I'm getting undefined value.
The structure of the JSON data is something like this

```
    {
        "historykey": 4,
        "insertdateUTC": "2013-11-15T23:21:44.247",

    }
```

However if i use

```
model_object.get("historykey")
```

I'm getting proper data.
My question is why i'm not getting data using member.get("HistoryKey").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `set` to change the attributes of your model:

```
this.set('HistoryKey', note.historykey);
this.set('InsertDate', note.insertdateUTC);
this.set('MemberKey', note.memberkey);
this.set('NoteDate', note.notedateUTC);
this.set('ContactNote', note.contactnote);
this.set('UserId', note.userid);
```

And `get` to access to the properties.

Comment: @AngshuGuha `=` operator is setting a property directly to the object while Backbone uses an internal object to handle the properties of a model.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this.set("HistoryKey", note.historykey)` in the `initialize` method. What you are doing is setting a property on the object, but what you want to do is set an attribute on the Backbone model. If in your example you'd write `console.log(this.HistoryKey)` in the `initialize` method, you *would* get the value you are looking for. Read this: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set